# Run Windows command (s) when new line added to text file?

Tags: windows

I've an application (not written by me) that writes text to a logfile in realtime. I want to create a script that:

1. monitors the logfile (which is in plain text)
2. generates an event for each new line added
3. the event processing will then interrogate the new line and then run one or more commands

How do i go about this? If I can do this in Powershell that would be perfect, but I'll consider any solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a file system watcher. [Powershell  FileSystemWatcher](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b) should help.